# in Linux, how to go to the folder above the symbolic link folder of the actual path?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

Say I got a folder with absolute location: /tmp/abc/def, and I created a symbolic link to this folder def, in my home directory. The symbolic link is also called def. Then after I get to the def from my home directory by calling:

```
cd ~/def
```

I then want to go to the folder "abc". What should I do then?

I've search for around 20 minutes but didn't find the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can not do the obvious `cd /tmp/abc`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `pwd -P` to get the "real" path, so something like this would work:

```
cd "$(pwd -P)/.."
```

Comment: I didn't know this before. Thanks :)

Comment: Works great on macOS out-of-the-box, unlike the other answer with just `cd ..`

Answer (score 0):

Type in:

```
cd ..
```

That should bring you to the parent directory of whatever your current directory is.

Comment: This solution has exactly the problem the OP wants to solve. When entering the directory via symlink, the `cd ..` will return to the directory that contains the symlink.

Comment: This solution works, but only in certain settings.  For example, in bash `set -P` will enable this, but `set +P` will cause it to fail.  In either case, `cd -P ..` should work.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: thanks, this method is clean and cool :)

Comment: The `cd -P ..` in comments here worked great in macOS out-of-the-box.

Comment: Why isn't `cd -P ..` the answer? `cd ..` has obviously been tried by anyone who googled this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use th `-P` flag with `cd`:

`cd -P ..`

This was pointed out above in comments, just adding this answer to give more visibility to that solution.